# How can I link my network user account to the Virtual PC setup on my machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, windows-xp, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am trying to test an issue in an application in which the error only occurs on Windows XP.  I have set up a Virtual PC XP instance on my Windows 7 machine.  The application I am trying to test is a click-once .NET application that auto-logs-in the current user based on their network username and password.

Is there a way I can either link the XPMUser to my network user ID or just use my network user account in my Virtual PC instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join your test VM to the domain and log in like you would any other machine. Don't treat a VM any differently than if it were a separate physical machine under your desk.